# Error running steam in Virtualbox debian guest: "libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast"

Tags: virtualbox, debian, graphics-card, steam

I have a Debian Sid guest running in Virtualbox (on a Debian host), where I installed the `steam` package from the `non-free` repository.

When I try to run `steam`, I get the following errors:

```
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

I found some other posts regarding this error message (e.g.*"[Steam not opening in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771032/steam-not-opening-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts/771507)"*) ... but none of them are about virtualbox, and they don't have answers that fix the problem I'm having. I have also tried using the `.deb` file provided from the steam website and ran into the same problem.

Most of the other "solutions" online suggest doing the following:

```
rm ~/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
rm ~/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

... and then running `steam` like this: `LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' DISPLAY=:0 steam` ... but none of this works for me, and I get the same error even after removing the libraries from the steam directory. `firmware-amd-graphics`, `libgl1-mesa-dri` and other 3D rendering libraries are installed and working correctly on both the host and guest, so that's not causing the problem.

I think the problem might actually have something to do with the fact that VirtualBox uses this virtual video card for the guests. When I run `lspci` from within the guest, this is the graphics card that shows up:

`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Graphics Adapter`

The actual video card, as displayed on the host is:

`Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445] (rev c1)`

which uses the `amdgpu` drivers.

I can't find solutions online that specifically address running `steam` on Debian *within Virtualbox* ... Does anyone know what I need to do to fix this error, and get steam running inside a VM?

Answer (score 1):

I've had trouble with this and this worked for me you have to kind of prepare steam by doing this:

In your terminal enter these commands:

```
cd ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/

./steam
```

also, run:

```
steam
```

a couple of times to get it running if it freezes first time just ctrl+c,

It should work on the second try.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.

Comment: You have to pre-prepare steam because the command "steam" doesn't do that, almost like compiling it

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem. Basically, the Steam client for Linux requires 32-bit libraries to run, and the default install for Debian only supported the 64-bit architecture.

To fix this, I started with a fresh VM (without Steam installed), and then ran the following commands to add support for 32-bit (i386) libs:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install steam
```

And everything is working now!